# In ListView make the first item as a title ,and index issue

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am trying to display the title for the Navigation Drawer,It displayed properly but the problem is that when I am trying to click on the first item in the navigation drawer that is home ,it will display the Queues.class instead of expected class.And when click on the last item in the navigation Drawer application get crash.I just want to Display the Title in the navigation Drawer and last item click will show proper activity.Also problem is that the title display two times.

```
package com.abc;
//import android.app.Activity;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.BaseBundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class navigation_drawer_class extends Activity
//public class navigation_drawer_class extends ListActivity

{
     private static final int Copy = 0;
     int a =0;
     public static FrameLayout frameLayout;
     TextView mytextview;
     public static ListView mDrawerList;
     public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     String Fullname;
     protected String[] listArray = {"Home","Queue","Inbox","Create Ticket","Search","Clients","App settings"};
     protected static int position;
     private static boolean isLaunch = true;

     //*****************************************

     JSONObject post_details_obj,post_obj;

     public static String FIRST_NAME="first_name",LAST_NAME="last_name";
     JSONArray staff_data_array;
     //*****************************************
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
     Operation op=new Operation();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //------------------ THIS ONE -------------------------
      getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.crop3);//THIS ONE FOR THE DRAWER LOGO
      //--------------------- THIS ONE ----------------------

      frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
      mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
     /// mDrawerList.setAdapter(null);
      //***************** To Set the Welcome client ******************************************

    //========= THIS ONE ===============

         new getname().execute();
        //========= THIS ONE ===============
          /*  mDrawerList.setAdapter(null);
            View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview,null);

            TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerview_id);
            headerValue.setText("Mydata");

            mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);//addHeaderView(header, null, false) 
            */
          /* TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
          Log.d("Fullname in oncreate : ",Fullname.toString());
          tv.setText(Fullname);  */


      //******************To Set the Welcome client  ******************************************

      mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));



      mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
      {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
               }
      });
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

          actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,      // host Activity 
        mDrawerLayout,     // DrawerLayout object 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,     // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret 
        R.string.open_drawer,       // "open drawer" description for accessibility 
        R.string.close_drawer)      // "close drawer" description for accessibility 
      {
       @Override
       public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) 
       {
        getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
       {
           getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
       {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) 
       {
        super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
       }
      };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    if(isLaunch){
       isLaunch = false;
       openActivity(0);

      }
     }

     protected void openActivity(int position) {

    //  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    //  setTitle(listArray[position]);
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
      navigation_drawer_class.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.



      switch (position) {
      case 0:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Folders.class));

       break;

      //case 2:
      case 1:

       Intent i=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,Queues.class);
       i.putExtra("set_queue","set");  
       startActivity(i);    
       break;

      case 2:
      //case 3:
       Intent inbox=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,Tickets.class);
       inbox.putExtra("filter_id","&vis_filter_id=1");          
       inbox.putExtra("title","Inbox");
       inbox.putExtra("set_queue","no");
       startActivity(inbox);
       break;

      case 3:
      //case 4:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, New_Ticket_step1.class));
       break;

      case 4:
      //case 5:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Search.class));
       break;

      case 5:
      //case 6:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Client.class));
       break;

      case 6:
      //case 7:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
           break;

      default:


       break;
      }   

/*
      switch (position) {
      case 0:
           break;
      case 1:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Folders.class));
       break;

      case 2:
       Intent i=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,Queues.class);
       i.putExtra("set_queue","set");  
       startActivity(i);    
       break;

      case 3:
       Intent inbox=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,Tickets.class);
       inbox.putExtra("filter_id","&vis_filter_id=1");          
       inbox.putExtra("title","Inbox");
       inbox.putExtra("set_queue","no");
       startActivity(inbox);
       break;

      case 4:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, New_Ticket_step1.class));
       break;

      case 5:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Search.class));
       break;

      case 6:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Client.class));
       break;

      case 7:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
           break;

      default:
       break;
      } 
    */
      //Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
      //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
          // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
          if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
          {
                    return true;
          }
          switch (item.getItemId())
          {
                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
     }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
       {

            //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
            //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() 
     {
      if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList))
      {
          mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
      }
      else 
      {
          mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
      }
     }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
        private class getname extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
        {

            Dialog dialog;
            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() 
            {
                dialog = new Dialog(navigation_drawer_class.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {

                String STAFF_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"staff","get_staff_details","");
                staff_data_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(STAFF_URL+"&vis_encode=json",navigation_drawer_class.this);
                return staff_data_array;

            }
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(JSONArray staff_data_array) 
            {   
                super.onPostExecute(staff_data_array);
                String staff_data_result =staff_data_array.toString();

              try {
                post_obj = staff_data_array.getJSONObject(0);
                String fname=post_obj.getString(FIRST_NAME);
                String lname=post_obj.getString(LAST_NAME);
                //Fullname =fname+" "+lname;
                Fullname =fname;

                if(Fullname=="")
                {
                    Fullname="Admin";
                }

                Fullname="Welcome "+Fullname;


                View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview,null);
                TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerview_id);
                headerValue.setText(Fullname);
                mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);//addHeaderView(header, null, false) */



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


        //-----------------------------------------------------------

}
```